# Lift up a text CSS

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/WwhNM/2/

How to lift up the text in #title with 5px?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Subtract `5px` from the `padding-top` on `#kontainer`.
- Add `padding-bottom: 5px` on `#title`.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/WwhNM/6/

Answer (score 2):

Add `padding-bottom:5px;`
Modify padding-top, padding-left, etc. to move the content around.